# Parse.com Add Object as Relation in Android

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am having trouble adding my message as a relation in parse.  I am not getting any error and nothing is submitting inside of Parse.

Group has relationship Messages
Group has already been set at the top of the page.

```
ParseObject messageToSend = new ParseObject("Message");
messageToSend.put("FromUser", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
messageToSend.put("Content", uiMessageToSend.getText().toString());

ParseRelation<ParseObject> relation = Group.getRelation("Messages");
relation.add(messageToSend);

Group.saveInBackground();
```

Comment: You have to save the ParseObject "messageToSend" before saving "Group".

Comment: @Jeremy, My answer solved your question?

Comment: @Jeremy, you should accept the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
ParseObject messageToSend = new ParseObject("Message");

        messageToSend.put("FromUser", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
        messageToSend.put("Content", uiMessageToSend.getText().toString());

        ParseRelation<ParseObject> relation = Group.getRelation("Messages");
        messageToSend.put("YOUR_RELATION", relation);

        messageToSend.saveInBackground();
```